# Dollar operator as function argument for sapply not working as expected

Tags: r, lapply, sapply, dollar-sign

I have the following list

```
test_list=list(list(a=1,b=2),list(a=3,b=4))
```

and I want to extract all elements with list element name `a`.

I can do this via

```
sapply(test_list,`[[`,"a")
```

which gives me the correct result

```
#[1] 1 3
```

When I try the same with Rs dollar operator `$`, I get `NULL`

```
sapply(test_list,`$`,"a")
#[[1]]
#NULL
#
#[[2]]
#NULL
```

However, if I use it on a single element of `test_list` it works as expected

```
`$`(test_list[[1]],"a")
#[1] 1
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I've been able to determine it's a combination of two things.

First, [the second element of `$` is matched but not evaluated so it cannot be a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18228613/868622).

Secondly, when arguments are passed to functions they are assigned to the corresponding variables in the function call. When passed to `sapply` `"a"` is assigned to a variable and therefore will no longer work with `$`. We can see this by occurring by running

```
sapply("a", print)
[1] "a"
  a 
"a"
```

This can lead to peculiar results like this

```
sapply(test_list, function(x, a) {`$`(x, a)})
[1] 1 3
```

Where despite `a` being a variable (which hasn't even been assigned) `$` matches it to the names of the elements in the list.

Comment: Very interesting answer! It basically shows that already `x="a";"$"(test_list[[1]],x);` gives an incorrect result.

Comment: Also, similar to what you have said, `"$"(test_list[[1]],a)` gives `1`, although no object `a` was defined.

Answer (score 11):

**evaluation vs. none**

`[[` evaluates its argument whereas `$` does not.  `L[[a]]` gets the component of `L` whose name is held in the variable `a`.  `$` just passes the argument name itself as a character string so `L$a` finds the `"a"` component of `L`.  `a` is not regarded as a variable holding the component name -- just a character string.

Below `L[[b]]` returns the component of `L` named `"a"` because the variable `b` has the value `"a"` whereas `L$b` returns the componet of `L` named `"b"` because with that syntax `b` is not regarded as a variable but is regarded as a character string which itself is passed.

```
L <- list(a = 1, b = 2)
b <- "a"
L[[b]] # same as L[["a"]] since b holds a
## [1] 1
L$b  # same as L[["b"]] since b is regarded as a character string to be passed
## [1] 2
```

**sapply**

Now that we understand the key difference bewteen $ and [[ to see what is going on with `sapply` consider this example.  We have made each element of `test_list` into a `"foo"` object and defined our own `$.foo` and `[[.foo` methods which simply show what R is passing to the method via the `name` argument:

```
foo_list <- test_list
class(foo_list[[1]]) <- class(foo_list[[2]]) <- "foo"

"$.foo" <- "[[.foo" <- function(x, name) print(name)

result <- sapply(foo_list, "$", "a")
## "..."
## "..."

result2 <- sapply(foo_list, "[[", "a")    
## [1] "a"
## [1] "a"
```

What is happening in the first case is that `sapply` is calling `whatever$...` and `...` is not evaluated so it would be looking for a list component which is  literally named `"..."` and, of course, there is no such component so `whatever$...` is NULL hence the NULLs shown in the output in the question.  In the second case `whatever[[[...]]` evaluates to `whatever[["a"]]` hence the observed result.