# Building a reference to a named column out of a passed vector

Tags: r

If I run a sum function and explicitly call the named column I have no problem.  But if I try to build the reference out of a passed character vector I get this error.

All the answers to this error I can find talk about characters in the column itself, which is not my problem.  It runs fine if I type it out.  I think if has something to do with `$`.

Thanks in advance.

```
pollut<-"nitrate"

> sum(test1$nitrate, na.rm=TRUE)

[1] 67.089

> sum(paste("test1$",pollut,sep=""), na.rm=TRUE)
```

> Error in sum(paste("test1$", pollut, sep = ""), na.rm = TRUE) :
> invalid 'type' (character) of argument

Edit...A suggested answer did identify the problem but not the solution as Richard so clearly did.

Comment: What makes you think that `test1$nitrate` is the same as `"test1$nitrate"`?  They are absolutely not the same, as you have discovered.  I think you want `sum(test1[[pollut]], na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: You can't use the `$` operator with variables. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/select-a-data-frame-column-using-and-the-name-of-the-column-in-a-variable/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34544888/dollar-operator-as-function-argument-for-sapply-not-working-as-expected/

Comment: Richard, thank you that worked.  I would agree they aren't the same but as I'm just learning I was not aware that it evaluated differently as I'd used that structure elsewhere and it worked.

Comment: NGaffney thanks. I'd assumed that was the case.